# Java change String using a JButton and JTextField

Tags: java

I wanna ask how do I change String using a text box `String = textbox.getText();` I already tried this using a `JButton` , but it doesn't work, can you help me?

```
    public static String a = " ";  //on the start
    textfield = new JTextField();
    textfield.setText("text");
    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("button");
            btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    a = textfield.getText();
                }});
```

I tried all of this, but it doesn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: are you trying to change the `textfiled` text to " " when `btnNewButton` is clicked?

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: In the JFrame textbox I write a text, i click at the button (in the code up) and try to change String using mt textbox(text in text box = String), but when I click it doesnt work.

Comment: You code is working perfectly for me. Check [this](https://gist.github.com/seenukarthi/8a04dfbaa372dee02f623bf640ca28c3) for full code.

Comment: Than I don't know what is wrong? Maybe because I am using Eclipse mars for java? That's not why it doesn't work. I don;t know what is it?